# USD - MS CRM - New CRM Page is not Working

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, unified-service-desk

In my implementation (configuring from scratch), when I click on a button from Contact, on click of a button, I am calling an action which will open a new case with Customer Data prepopulated on New case form.

Below are events that triggered after clicking the button.

[image]

But in USD, Case Hosted Control s opening with empty page.

I have did the same implementation in another environment, where Sample Configuration data was installed and it worked fine. See the below events that triggered after clicking the button.

[image]

So many events triggered in my environment, where I have sample data configuration. What have I missed?

Comment: Do you have windows navigation rule set up to open your case from the contact form?